# Notify every new ledger

Tags: ledger, go-sdk

How I can get notify (like newblockinfo in bitcoin or getlastblock in ethereum or bitcoin) on new ledger in blockchain with go-sdk

Answer (score 5):

Just use [`Client.StreamLedgers`](https://godoc.org/github.com/stellar/go/clients/horizon#Client.StreamLedgers) method:

```
client := DefaultPublicNetClient
cursor := Cursor("now")

// Call `cancel()` to stop streaming
ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())

err := client.StreamLedgers(ctx, &cursor, func(l Ledger) {
    fmt.Println(l.Sequence)
})

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```